# How can I modify dmy() in lubridate function to output the 1900s instead of the 2000s?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have data that only show the last two digits of a year. Using
`dmy("090965")`
the output is "2065-09-09".
I would like it to be "1965-09-09". How do I modify this to get the output?

```
library(lubridate)
dmy("090965")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing things:

```
a=dmy("090965") 
year(a)=1965  

# or if you have a vector with multiple years: 
year(a)=year(a)-100

> a
[1] "1965-09-09"
```

Comment: This really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across another possible solution in case there is a cutoff year after which you require the dates to start. Just thought to update this in case I need it in the future. This only works for the 1900s and 2000s

```
library(lubridate)
# if you require dates after 1908
parse_date_time2("090965", "dmy", cutoff_2000 = 8L)

# if you require dates after 1960
> parse_date_time2("090965", "dmy", cutoff_2000 = 60L)
[1] "1965-09-09 UTC" 

# if you require dates after 1970
> parse_date_time2("090965", "dmy", cutoff_2000 = 70L)
[1] "2065-09-09 UTC"
```